# DataTrigger Comapring Date Values to set Cell Style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

**I am creating a Fault Log Application, bound to a database**

The primary use of what  I want is to format the DateTime cell to RED if the DateTime
listed is greater than 3 weeks prior to the current date.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="379" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,36,0,0" Name="dataGridLog" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" SelectionChanged="dataGridLog_SelectionChanged" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="dataGridLog_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dateColumn" Header="Date" Width="80" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="dateColumnTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=DateSent, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="80" />
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DateSent, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}, Converter={x:Reference mIsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=3}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="dateColumnTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>-->
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="priorityColumn" Header="Priority" Width="80" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="priorityColumnTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Priority}" Width="80" />
                    <!--<DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Priority}" Value="Urgent">
                            <Setter TargetName="priorityColumnTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="titleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Fault}" Header="Title" Width="270" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(String))]
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan span = curDate.Subtract(date);

        return span.Days;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
        {
            return resultDateTime;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to bind the converter, not able to convert the dates.

Comment: If DateSent is a DateTime you can't cast to an int.

Comment: Thanks, LPL.
Now casted as DateTime

Comment: But now your ConverterParameter is wrong. 3 is an int. What holds the parameter, years, days, hours? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to format the cells background to 'red' where the time between today and the date listed is greater than 3 weeks. I just need to do that.

Comment: This: `{x:Reference mIsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=3}` - how does it know what to do with the DateTime you are trying to pass to it?

Comment: I've changed the last method to return the difference in days. I am not getting 'Unresolved Reference: DateConverter'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have declared your `Converter` in `Resources`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter x:Key="IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

you can reference it like this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DateSent, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="dateColumnTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Your `DataTrigger` compares with True. Therefore your `Converter` should return a bool.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(bool))]
public class IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan span = curDate.Subtract(date);

        return span.TotalDays > (int)parameter * 7;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact solution I needed :D.. I also noticed I needed to further add `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FautLog"` in `<Window>`.  
Lastly, the `span.TotalDays > (int)parameter * 7;` throws an 'Invalid Cast' Exception

Comment: Have to cast the parameter as an int32, `int param = Int32.Parse(parameter.ToString());`, and then `return span.TotalDays > param*7;`, for it to work :D

Comment: You're right, of course parameter is a string and you have to parse it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Perfect. I set multiple triggers to set row background colours depending on date being in the future, today, or in the past. Thank you hero from 2014.